# How to get the same output as in TUGBoat article "Tracing paragraphs"?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, tugboat

Recently I began to read a very interesting TUGBoat article ["Tracing paragraphs"](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-3/tb117wermuth.pdf) by [Udo Wermuth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/131874/udo-wermuth).

There is the example-1 from the article (with header and footer added by logic considerations):

```
\pretolerance=100
\tolerance=200
\hsize=225.0pt
\tracingparagraphs=1
\noindent
Note: {\sl pretolerance\/} is \the\pretolerance\
and {\sl tolerance\/} is \the\tolerance, the
{\it hsize\/} is~\the\hsize.

This is a nonsense text to serve as a
constructed example that shows all kind of trace
lines. It contains~inline mathematics and text in
columns. The formula $2\times 2^2 = 8$ is simple
mathematics as well as formula $\root3 \of 8 = 2$
or what do you think? Now a declaration or
definition for a three columns tabbing
environment is made.
\settabs 3 \columns \+&&End of example:\cr
\end
```

The log file in the article indicates that `\nine...` fonts are used, so I added `\ninepoint` macro from [manmac.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/base/manmac.tex). Compilation failed, and I started to `grep` things on which it failed one by one in `manmac.tex` and add them to the example. Then `dvi` file matched what is in the article. But `log` file still did not match. I had to add `\hyphenation{col-umns}` because this word is not hyphenated by default in plain TeX.

Then `log` file started to match perfectly up to line 38. This is line 38 from article vs my run:

```
@\penalty via @@5 b=10 p=500 d=250400

@\penalty via @@5 b=8 p=500 d=250324
```

From this moment an up till the end the numbers started to differ wildly.

How to get the same output as in the example-1?

---

This is the additional header that I added:

```
\font\ninerm=cmr9
\font\sixrm=cmr6
\font\ninei=cmmi9
\font\sixi=cmmi6
\font\ninesy=cmsy9
\font\sixsy=cmsy6
\font\nineit=cmti9
\font\ninesl=cmsl9
\font\ninebf=cmbx9
\font\sixbf=cmbx6
\font\ninett=cmtt9
\newskip\ttglue

\def\ninepoint{\def\rm{\fam0\ninerm}%
  \textfont0=\ninerm \scriptfont0=\sixrm \scriptscriptfont0=\fiverm
  \textfont1=\ninei \scriptfont1=\sixi \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
  \textfont2=\ninesy \scriptfont2=\sixsy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
  \textfont3=\tenex \scriptfont3=\tenex \scriptscriptfont3=\tenex
  \def\it{\fam\itfam\nineit}%
  \textfont\itfam=\nineit
  \def\sl{\fam\slfam\ninesl}%
  \textfont\slfam=\ninesl
  \def\bf{\fam\bffam\ninebf}%
  \textfont\bffam=\ninebf \scriptfont\bffam=\sixbf
   \scriptscriptfont\bffam=\fivebf
  \def\tt{\fam\ttfam\ninett}%
  \textfont\ttfam=\ninett
  \tt \ttglue=.5em plus.25em minus.15em
  \normalbaselineskip=11pt
  \def\MF{{\manual hijk}\-{\manual lmnj}}%
  \let\sc=\sevenrm
  \let\big=\ninebig
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height8pt depth3pt width0pt}%
  \normalbaselines\rm}
\ninepoint
\hyphenation{col-umns}
```

Comment: There is a very large macro file associated with this article; I haven't had time to explore it thoroughly.  What I *have* confirmed, however, is that the file `tugboat.sty` is input, and this in turn inputs `tugboat.cmn`, which contains the hyphenation exception `\hyphenation{col-umns}`, a word that has caused problems in the past.  `tugboat.sty` also defines `\ninepoint`.  This file is included in TeX Live, so you should be able to start by inputting it and see if anything changes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed, using `\input tugboat.sty` and `\ninepoint` fixes it! But one has to install `texlive-publishers` package (in Debian). How to factor out the necessary changes from `tugboat.sty` to make the output match the article using only plain TeX? I need to know what is the cause of difference of the numbers. (I wonder how an author who uses plain TeX over 30 years could write an article which relies on huge external libraries, without explaining anything.)

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Maybe you should grep `tugboat.sty` and `tugboat.cmn` for all parameters that can influence the computation of demerits,  such as `\emergencystretch`...

Comment: @frougon grep "emergencystretch", "tolerance", "looseness", "demerits" is empty. Only "penalty" produces something. Most interesting are `\clubpenalty=10000` and `\widowpenalty=10000`, but they have no effect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ``huge external libraries''. I wrote
this article for TUGboat and they require that I use their macro
files. I haven't mentioned tugboat.sty or tugboat.cmn and their
version numbers (the current files have a different version number
than those that I used back then) because I thought that is obvious as
all journals have their macros. I don't know what packages Debian has
but the tugboat.* files are available on CTAN.

Comment: To your question: I didn't expect that anyone runs this example under
plain TeX as the 9pt font is explicitly mentioned in the text so it
cannot be executed without activating these fonts. You get the output
if you change your copy of manmac's \ninepoint to use scriptfonts of
7pt not 6pt. Tugboat has its own \ninepoint macro.
OK I just see that David Carlisle has written an answer. And a Thank you that you find the article interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that the `\ninepoint` you defined was using a 6pt script size, but tugboat uses 7pt, copying a few more tugboat definitions gives

```
@\penalty via @@5 b=10 p=500 d=250400
```

from a modified document

```
\catcode`\@=11
%\input tugboat.sty
%\input tugboat.cmn
\font\ninerm=cmr9
\font\sixrm=cmr6
\font\ninei=cmmi9
\font\sixi=cmmi6
\font\ninesy=cmsy9
\font\sixsy=cmsy6
\font\nineit=cmti9
\font\ninesl=cmsl9
\font\ninebf=cmbx9
\font\sixbf=cmbx6
\font\ninett=cmtt9
\newskip\ttglue

\def\@additionsto#1{\expandafter\the\csname @addsto\string#1\endcsname}
\expandafter\newtoks\csname @addsto\string\ninepoint\endcsname

\newbox\struttbox
\def\strutt{\relax\ifmmode\copy\struttbox\else\unhcopy\struttbox\fi}

\def\setttglue{%
  \edef\@thefont{\the\font}%  to restore this font after the setting
  \tt \ttglue=.5em plus .25em minus .15em
  \@thefont}

\def\ninepoint{\normalbaselineskip=11pt
  \abovedisplayskip=2.5pt plus 2.5pt minus 1pt
  \belowdisplayskip=2.5pt plus 2.5pt minus 1pt
  \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt plus 2.5pt
  \belowdisplayshortskip=1pt plus 2.5pt minus 1pt
  \def\rm{\fam\z@\ninerm}%
  \textfont\z@=\ninerm \scriptfont\z@=\sevenrm
  \def\oldstyle{\fam\@ne\ninei}%
  \textfont\@ne=\ninei \scriptfont\@ne=\seveni
  \textfont\tw@=\ninesy \scriptfont\tw@=\sevensy
  \def\it{\fam\itfam\nineit}%
  \textfont\itfam=\nineit
  \def\sl{\fam\slfam\ninesl}%
  \textfont\slfam=\ninesl
  \def\bf{\fam\bffam\ninebf}%
  \textfont\bffam=\ninebf \scriptfont\bffam=\sevenbf
  \def\smc{\ninesmc}%
  \def\SMC{\eightrm}%
  \font\manual=logo9
  \font\manualsl=logosl10 at 9pt
  \def\tt{\ninett}%
        \setttglue
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height 6.75pt depth 2.25pt width\z@}%
  \setbox\struttbox=\hbox{\vrule height 7.75pt depth 3.25pt width\z@}%
  \normalbaselines \rm
  \@additionsto\ninepoint }
\ninepoint
\hyphenation{col-umns}




\newskip\ttglue
\ninepoint

\pretolerance=100
\tolerance=200
\hsize=225.0pt
\tracingonline1
\tracingparagraphs=1

%\tracingall
\noindent
Note: {\sl pretolerance\/} is \the\pretolerance\
and {\sl tolerance\/} is \the\tolerance, the
{\it hsize\/} is~\the\hsize.

This is a nonsense text to serve as a
constructed example that shows all kind of trace
lines. It contains~inline mathematics and text in
columns. The formula $2\times 2^2 = 8$ is simple
mathematics as well as formula $\root3 \of 8 = 2$
or what do you think? Now a declaration or
definition for a three columns tabbing
environment is made.
\settabs 3 \columns \+&&End of example:\cr
\end
```

Answer (score 3):

in retrospect it seems obvious that for Udo's examples, we should have turned off tugboat.sty's hyphenation exceptions (and anything else that might have affected line breaking). None of us thought of it. Sorry.